Showing first not-sigificant number using package siunitx
How can I get LaTeX to show a zero (0) in brackets after the decimal point, when using the siunitx package?
I want the output to look like this: 4,399(0) kg
But right now it looks like this 4,399 kg - the 0 gets completely ignored
My input is
\SI{4,399(0)}{\kilo\gram}

It works fine with other numbers, just 0 seems to be a problem.

You need option retain-zero-uncertainty:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\qty{4,399(0)}{\kilo\gram}

\qty[retain-zero-uncertainty]{4,399(0)}{\kilo\gram}

\end{document}


Thank you very much. It worked well. Can i also get this to work globally for all zeros in brackets?

@FabianErhart Not at present: that would be a feature request (for which I'd need some pointers to where it's used in typeset material)

@JosepfWright I tried to use following command in the preamble: \sisetup{detect-all,retain-zero-uncertainty} and it worked fine. I don't know if this is intended, but it worked.
